# Oracle SQL Developer - Case sensitive

Tags: plsqldeveloper

I'm creating procedure, but SQL Developer throws a weird error. I make a screenshot.

[image]

Table columns have names with small letters. I wrote small letters! But SQL Developer say, that I wrote big letters and big letters of course doesn't match real column names...

Sorry for my English, I hope you will understand.

Comment: Oracle is not case-sensitive.  There's something else going on.

Comment: @Marc that is incorrect, if anything within quotes is case sensitive in Oracle, so creating a table/column name with small case in quotes becomes case sensitive. Look at my answer which demonstrates this

Comment: @Sathya, Thanks for that. I learned 2 things: (1) you are correct about the case sensitivity w/quotes, and (2) such a thing as SqlFiddle.com exists; very cool.

Comment: @Marc SQLFiddle.com is indeed very cool :) you're welcome!

Answer (score 2):

If you are *absolutely* sure that you did create the column names with "ID_pr" style, then when querying, you will need to query them with the quotes.

```
SELECT  "PRACOVNIK"."ID_pr" ..
```

like so.

Example of a SQLFiddle which demonstrates this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/93b49/5